# HttpClient does not work as opposed to Http for backend queries with Angular

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, http, angular-httpclient

Ok, I'll explain my problem. I'm starting on Angular and this is the first time I'm doing a REST API, so something can escape me.

In my case, I use a Period object in `Typescript` and in `C#`, here they are:

**Period TS:**

```
export class Period {
    id: number;
    year: string;
    month: string;
    blocked: boolean;

    constructor(id: number, year: string, month: string, blocked: boolean) {
        this.id = id;
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.blocked = blocked;
    }
}
```

**Period C#:**

```
public class Period
  {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "year")]
    public string Year { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "month")]
    public string Month { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "blocked")]
    public bool Blocked { get; set; }

    public Period() { }
  }
```

Until then, I managed to recover data from my database via Postman.

**Postman: GET** -> `https://localhost:5001/api/period/GetAllPeriods`

```
[
  {
     "id": 122,
     "year": "2019",
     "month": "03",
     "blocked": false
  },
  {
     "id": 121,
     "year": "2019",
     "month": "02",
     "blocked": false
  }, ...
]
```

[image]

I did some research and several tests, and the code below works.
I retrieve my `JSON` data that I transform into a Period object list into `Typescript`.
Then, I display them on my page and everything works correctly.

But on the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/http/Http), it is written that `Http` is obsolete and that it is better to use `HttpClient`.

**period.service.ts: Http**

```
export class PeriodService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  //Http
  getPeriods(): Observable<Period[]> {
    return this.http.get('/api/period/GetAllPeriods')
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError),
        map(response => {
          const periods = response.json();
          return periods.map((period) => new Period(period.id, period.year, period.month, period.blocked));
        })
      );
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
      console.error(error);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  };
}
```

So I tried to use `HttpClient`.
However, I can not recover the data at my service.

**period.service.ts: HttpClient**

```
export class PeriodService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //HttpClient
  getPeriods(): Observable<Period[]> {
    return this.http.get<Period[]>('https://localhost:5001/api/period/GetAllPeriods')
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
      console.error(error);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  };
}
```

[image]

To be clearer, I get the `JSON` data from the API, but when I use the `HttpClient` service, an error message appears in the browser console because it can not find the data yet accessible.
So, I think my problem comes from service with `HttpClient`.

If you have ideas I am interested.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's been several days that I am stuck on this problem, and once my question asked, I just found the solution ...

My problem was: `import {HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule} from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';`

It turns out that to develop my application I started using `HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule`.
But this module is incompatible with `HttpClient`.
It must be removed to use `HttpClient`.

Now my application is working properly and displays the data.

Answer (score 0):

In your component, when you make a call to the method getPeriods(), add a subscribe in it since it returns an observable type.

this.getPeriods().subscribe(Response => { console.log(Response)});